# Handling Windows messages so that my application responds correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, message-queue

I had an old piece of code that I wrote about 15 years ago to do some file manipulation, which runs through a script to process 1/2 sourcefiles and output to 1/2 outputfiles and I've been trying to write it 'properly' so that it will run under Windows 7/8 as a scheduled task.

I've ported it to Visual Studio 2013 Express, and managed to get it to work (execute and generate the desired results) pretty quickly, processing my text input file, stripping rubbish out of it, and generating a formatted CSV file in about 38 seconds, however it Ghosts, and goes non-responsive until such time as the processing of the file completes, which is okish for user execution, but Windows 7 and 8 don't like running it as a scheduled task, and close it as soon as it ghosts.

I've tried re-writing the large chunk of processing code so that it returns to the main message handling loop after each line of script, and this functions, albeit about ten-twenty times slower (depending on whether I'm using GetMessage or PeekMessage, however I'm still struggling with the application ghosting, despite each line of script only taking a few milliseconds to run.

My Main Window code is currently;

```
while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    while ((PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, WM_COMMAND - 1, PM_REMOVE) > 0) || 
        (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_COMMAND+1, 0xFFFF, PM_REMOVE) > 0)) 
        // While there are any system messages with a value <> WM_COMMAND, 
        // Process these first
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) 
        // Process one WM_COMMAND message i.e. one of mine.
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

where my WndProc function has a giant case statement that processes all my posted messages to perform one sub-task of my file processing and all the windows system-type responses. I've cut out some of the 'doing stuff' commands, but you'll get the gist
it's a;
until we reach my iteration bit in the scriptfile;
  process phase 1
until we finish processing the sourcefile or go round enough iterations;
  process phase 2
until we reach the end of the sourcefile
  process phase 3
end

```
switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
        //////////////////////////////
        /* Start of my menu uptions */
        //////////////////////////////
    case MI_FILE_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        return(0);

    case MI_RUN_EXECUTE:
        // * Open Necessary Files * //
        // * Start Processing ScriptFile * //
        phase = 1;
        command = 'A';
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_PHASE_1, lParam);
        return(0);

    case MI_PHASE_1:
        nextcommand = ProcessCommand(command);
        if (ScriptFileComplete)
        {
            // We've reached the end of the script - stop processing
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_SCRIPT_COMPLETE, lParam);
            break;
        }
        else if (nextcommand = '<')
        {
            // prep for start of phase 2
            phase = 2;
            tiptr = tptr;
            command = nextcommand;
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_PHASE_2, lParam);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // process the nextcommand
            command = nextcommand;
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_PHASE_1, lParam);
            break;
        }
        return(0);

    case MI_PHASE_2:
        nextcommand = ProcessCommand(command);
        redrawscreen(hWnd);
        if (nextcommand == '>')
        {
            // we're at the end of the iteration
            if (UseIterationCount)
            {
                IterationCount--;
                if (IterationCount <= 0)
                {
                    phase = 3;
                    command = nextcommand;
                    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_PHASE_3, lParam);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (ScriptFileComplete)
        {
            // We've reached the end of the script - stop processing
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_SCRIPT_COMPLETE, lParam);
            break;
        }
        else if (SourceFileAComplete)
            // We've reached the end of the Source File - stop processing
        {
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_SCRIPT_COMPLETE, lParam);
            break;
        }
        else // All's normal and we're just processing the next command
        {
            command = nextcommand;
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_PHASE_2, lParam);
            break;
        }
        return(0);

    case MI_PHASE_3:
        nextcommand = ProcessCommand(command);
        command = nextcommand;
        // test to see if we go round phase 3 loop again
        if ((!ScriptFileComplete) && (!SourceFileAComplete))
        {
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_PHASE_3, lParam);
            break;
        }
        else // we've cleared that and we're at scriptfile EOF
        {
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_SCRIPT_COMPLETE, lParam);
            break;
        }
        return(0);

    case MI_SCRIPT_COMPLETE:
        // We're at the end of the script - close things down.
        CloseFiles();
        DrawMenuBar(hWnd);
        if (AutoExit)
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_QUIT, wParam, lParam);
        return(0);

    case MI_DO_NOTHING: // blank code for initial entry to main message loop
        return(0);

    default: // somehow an invalid message was posted
        log("invalid message was posted");
        return(0);
    }

case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
    redrawscreen(hWnd);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    return(0);

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return(0);

default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return(0);
```

}

So the idea is that after each call to processCommand (i.e. carry out one line of my script processing), return to the main message handle, respond to any events (like someone moving the window or clicking on the close button), and then process the next line of my script.

I'm clearly missing something (or lots of things) regarding which messages I should be checking and processing on a regular basis, so if anyone can offer suggestions/advice as to;
What messages should I be handling before all others?
How often should my application be checking for system messages?
Am I going about this completely wrong? 
e.g. should I be threading the processing code? - the app shouldn't require any user interaction while it's running, but it would be good practise to allow a user to move/resize/quit it, which I was hoping to achieve through posting messages back to WM_COMMAND

Thank you very much for even reading this far. Any and all advice no matter how sharp (if it helps) appreciated.

Richard.

---

### - UPDATE -

Thanks both for the pointers - it's clear that this does warrant threading my slow file access bits of code, so I've re-written to do this, but now I'm just a bit stuck as to where I should do fire off the thread / join afterwards - There's lots of examples where the thread is fired off in the main window and then joined straight afterwards e.g.;

```
void My_Slow_Task(){
    ; // Process lots of data
}

int main(){
    std::thread t1(My_Slow_Task);
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

but as pointed out below doing this in my message handling block just means it sits there like a lemon until the thread finishes, but I need a user to be able to make changes to the outputfiles etc. before they kick off the file manipulation process (it can be automated, but it needs to be able to not be as well), so at the moment, I'm after something like;

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    // one of these messages is the menuitem for 'Run_my_big_chunk_of_processing' and sets 'ExecutingScript' to TRUE
    // another will be to change the location of the output file or edit the script etc.
    if (ExecutingScript == TRUE)
    {
        ExecutingScript = FALSE;
        std::thread t1(Run_my_big_chunk_of_processing);
        t1.join();
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_RUN_COMPLETE, lParam);
    // to do the close files, tidy up and feed back to the user.
    }
}
```

If anyone's knows how I can handle the request from the user to start the slow process and fire it off, without the GUI having to wait for it to finish before handling other messages, then that'll be it sorted.

---

### - SOLUTION? -

Use an outer control loop for user interaction while the thread isn't running, and an inner one for while it is;

```
 _twinMain()
{
// Initialise Stuff
// Pre-exec message loop
// Outer messagehandling loop
while (!AllDone)
// we're !AllDone on entry, and AllDone when the app gets
// a WM_QUIT or other triggered abort e.g. script failure
{
    // Pre/post-exec message loop
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (ExecutingScript) 
    // this will be set by auto-run in the ini file, 
    // or manually by a user clicking the menu option
    {
        std::thread t1(RunThread);

        // Exec message loop
        while (ExecutingScript)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
            // There may be no messages, as we could be in auto-run 
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        t1.join();
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_RUN_COMPLETE, lParam);
    }
}
return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Stop fiddling with the messages and thread it off to a BackgroundWorker or issue a threadpool task for it.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me Martin, I'll give that a crack.

Comment: I've tried using a backgroundworker, but I don't have the afxwin.h library. Is there any way to do multithreading in the Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition?
If not, are there other options to tidy the code?

Comment: What's the point of that first message loop?? Furthermore, `ExecutingScript` is set by another thread, which means that access must be synchronized. And the final message loop appears equally pointless. - the program is done when the worked thread is done, right?

Comment: The app starts, and depending upon whether we pass it certain parameters (via an ini file), it either auto-starts, runs the script against the input file(s) and generates the output file(s) and auto-exits, or starts, waits for a user to open/edit a script, input and output file, then for them to click the 'do it' button, and at the end give them a chance to look at the output before manually exiting (or running another script/ with a different input / output file - which the above won't do, as I've not wrapped a loop around that) hence 3 loops, which I know still looks very wrong.

Comment: The 'ExecutingScript' is only set to TRUE in the main program, once by either the ini-file saying auto-run, or the user clicking 'run now', eitherway, its the same PostMessage handled by the message handling case statement, and I'd only ever have one thread running the processing of the script (do I need to trap this? - or could I just grey out the option to click when already executing?), and this would set the ExecutingScript variable back to FALSE when it completes. Do I still need synchronisation?

Comment: Updated the message control loops above (again), so I've now only got two - one for pre/post execution, and an outer one for while the thread is running. - Is that any better? or can I do it all in one?

Comment: Ok, so all would be well now except... When the application exits, either from autoexit on finishing the script, or from a user click, I'm now left with a background process hogging resources. How should the above thread be terminated at the join?

Comment: @Msalters Ignore the last post - I'd managed to call DestroyWindow without doing a WM_QUIT, so it was the main window running in the background - Doh! Thanks for all your help, I'm learning... slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2013 has the C++11 `<thread>` stuff, no need for non-standard libraries. `std::aync(std::launch::async)` will run a background task, `std::future::wait_for` allows you to check from the messsage loop whether the operation has finished. Of course, you can also use a old-style `PostQuitMessage(WM_APP)` from the processing thread. Either way, after the message loops exits, call `.join()` on the worked thread to clean it up, then exit the main thread.

Comment: Ok, I've been doing a fair bit of reading about C++11 threads (but please feel free to point me to more). I've managed to get my chunk of processing to run as a thread, and it now takes a little longer to run, but still goes non-responsive. I think I'm just not grasping 'where' I should join, as it looks to me, I'm just asking the application to do exactly the same thing as it can't do anything until my slow code has finished running;

Comment: @RichardAcock: Your main thread should be _very_ responsive as it's doing nothing but run the main message loop. The `join` will block, yes, but that's done _after_ your message loop has exited anyway.

Comment: // Main message loop:
 while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
 {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
  if (ExecutingScript == TRUE)
  {
   ExecutingScript = FALSE;
   std::thread t1(Run_my_big_chunk_of_processing);
   t1.join();
   PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, MI_RUN_COMPLETE, lParam);
  }
 }

Comment: ok, thanks, that makes a lot more sense as to having the join straight after the thread starts then. Is it more likely then that I've got a.n.other chunk of slow code (like initialising files) that's causing the window to ghost then?

Comment: @RichardAcock: No, that join right there causes the non-responsiveness. The thread should start before the message loop and join afterwards.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes a lot more sense, except I need the user to be able to do some other things (like change the output file location, or modify the script), which posts the messages that I'm handling, before they click the 'Run_my_big_chunk_of_processing' option. Any suggestions of how I can get the user to fire it off, keep the GUI responsive, and leave the chunk running in the background until it completes?

Comment: Apologies, am I just being dim? Can I start the thread in my message handling case statement, or in the main message loop, and then join after the message loop exits?

Comment: You're a *Star* - Spot on! I resolved it with three message loops in the Main Window - I'll post above. If there's a better way, then please slap me and improve, but thank you for all your help. I'm finally getting the hand of threads :€)